# pytest/sqlalchemy object not bound to a session error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest

I read several posts like my issue but did not find anything relevant.
I have a desktop application and I try to perform some tests with pytest. For that, I run a MySQL server in a Docker container and use sqlalchemy to construct a session to add, update, etc objects. However I have this error I cannot figure how to fix `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance <Device at 0x7f4a38a01fd0> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed`

**dspt.db.__init__.py**

```
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()
user = os.environ.get('MYSQL_USER')
pwd = os.environ.get('MYSQL_PWD')
url = os.environ.get('MYSQL_URL', 'localhost')
db_url = f"mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pwd}@{url}/db?charset=utf8mb4&binary_prefix=true"
print(db_url)
engine = create_engine(db_url, encoding='utf-8')
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


@contextmanager
def db_session():
    """ Creates a SQLAlchemy session"""
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        # session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.expunge_all()
        session.close()
```

**test.py**

```
import pytest
from dspt.db import db_session, Base
from dspt.db.models import Device

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def get_device():
    return [Device(), Device(), Device()]


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def seed(get_device):
    devices = get_device
    with db_session() as session:
        for d in devices:
            session.add(d)
        session.commit()

def test_get_device(seed, get_device):
    with db_session() as session:
        devices = get_device
        res = session.query(Device)\
                     .filter(Device.serial == devices[0].serial)\
                     .all()

        assert len(res) == 1
```

Comment: The devices from `get_device` are expired after the commit in `seed` and detached when the session goes away.

Comment: ok, but a new session begins with the test ? why aren't the objects reloaded ? Does that mean the test begins whereas the session in `seed` is not closed yet ?

Comment: I think I've understood ! The `Device` objects are ORM objects and they are linked to a session. The session expired so the objects are deassociated of the session and I cannot get any of their argument. I thought they were python objects but they are ORM ones... Not so simple to understand though

Comment: Spot on! In addition `Session.commit` and `Session.rollback` expire all attributes in default configuration, so the detached objects don't have their data around. You can merge detached objects to a new session; `Session.merge` actually returns a new version bound to the new session. The idea behind all that is to prevent the user of the library from using possibly stale data (unless you really want to), as it may have changed already after a commit.